# Which perf events can use PEBS?

Tags: linux, performance, intel, performancecounter, perf

I want to understand which events can have the precise modifier on my
CPU (Sandy Bridge).

Intel Software Developer's Manual (Table 18-32. PEBS Performance
Events for Intel Microarchitecture Code Name Sandy Bridge) contains
only the following events: `INST_RETIRED`, `UOPS_RETIRED`,
`BR_INST_RETIRED`, `BR_MISP_RETIRED`, `MEM_UOPS_RETIRED`,
`MEM_LOAD_UOPS_RETIRED`, `MEM_LOAD_UOPS_LLC_HIT_RETIRED`. And [SandyBridge_core_V15.json](https://download.01.org/perfmon/SNB/SandyBridge_core_V15.json) lists the same events with PEBS > 0.

However there are [some examples](http://brendangregg.com/perf.html) of using `perf`, which add `:p` to the `cycles` event. And I can successfully run `perf record -e cycles:p` on my machine.

Also `perf record -e cycles:p -vv -- sleep 1` prints `precise_ip 1`. So does it mean that `CPU_CLK_UNHALTED` event actually uses PEBS?

Is it possible to get the full list of events, which support `:p`?

Comment: Ilya, try [ocperf from intel's pmu-tools](https://github.com/andikleen/pmu-tools). It has full event list of Intel CPUs (`ocperf list`?), and vanilla perf has no full list in userspace. Does perf report with header printing report nonzero precise_ip too (it can be required by record but disabled by kernel)? What is you kernel version? [`precise_ip` of 1 is "SAMPLE_IP must have constant skid"](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/uapi/linux/perf_event.h?v=4.8#L323)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is hack to support `cycles:p` on SandyBridge which has no PEBS for `CPU_CLK_UNHALTED.*`. The hack is implemented in the kernel part of `perf` in [`intel_pebs_aliases_snb()`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/x86/events/intel/core.c?v=4.8#L2739). When user requests `-e cycles` which is `PERF_COUNT_HW_CPU_CYCLES` (translates to `CPU_CLK_UNHALTED.CORE`) with nonzero `precise` modifier, this function will change hardware event to `UOPS_RETIRED.ALL` with PEBS:

```
  29    [PERF_COUNT_HW_CPU_CYCLES]      = 0x003c,

2739 static void intel_pebs_aliases_snb(struct perf_event *event)
2740 {
2741    if ((event->hw.config & X86_RAW_EVENT_MASK) == 0x003c) {
2742        /*
2743         * Use an alternative encoding for CPU_CLK_UNHALTED.THREAD_P
2744         * (0x003c) so that we can use it with PEBS.
2745         *
2746         * The regular CPU_CLK_UNHALTED.THREAD_P event (0x003c) isn't
2747         * PEBS capable. However we can use UOPS_RETIRED.ALL
2748         * (0x01c2), which is a PEBS capable event, to get the same
2749         * count.
2750         *
2751         * UOPS_RETIRED.ALL counts the number of cycles that retires
2752         * CNTMASK micro-ops. By setting CNTMASK to a value (16)
2753         * larger than the maximum number of micro-ops that can be
2754         * retired per cycle (4) and then inverting the condition, we
2755         * count all cycles that retire 16 or less micro-ops, which
2756         * is every cycle.
2757         *
2758         * Thereby we gain a PEBS capable cycle counter.
2759         */
2760        u64 alt_config = X86_CONFIG(.event=0xc2, .umask=0x01, .inv=1, .cmask=16);
2761 
2762        alt_config |= (event->hw.config & ~X86_RAW_EVENT_MASK);
2763        event->hw.config = alt_config;
2764    }
2765 }
```

The `intel_pebs_aliases_snb` hack is registered in [`3557 __init int intel_pmu_init(void)`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/x86/events/intel/core.c?v=4.8#L3557) for `case INTEL_FAM6_SANDYBRIDGE:` / `case INTEL_FAM6_SANDYBRIDGE_X:` as

```
3772        x86_pmu.event_constraints = intel_snb_event_constraints;
3773        x86_pmu.pebs_constraints = intel_snb_pebs_event_constraints;
3774        x86_pmu.pebs_aliases = intel_pebs_aliases_snb;
```

`pebs_aliases` is called from [`intel_pmu_hw_config()`](http://elixir.free-electrons.com/source/arch/x86/events/intel/core.c?v=4.8#L2814) when `precise_ip` is set to non-zero:

```
2814 static int intel_pmu_hw_config(struct perf_event *event)
2815 {

2821    if (event->attr.precise_ip) {

2828        if (x86_pmu.pebs_aliases)
2829            x86_pmu.pebs_aliases(event);
2830    }
```

The hack was implemented in 2012, lkml threads "[PATCH] perf, x86: Make cycles:p working on SNB", "[tip:perf/core] perf/x86: Implement cycles:p for SNB/IVB", cccb9ba9e4ee0d750265f53de9258df69655c40b, http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/tip/tip.git/commit/?id=cccb9ba9e4ee0d750265f53de9258df69655c40b:

> perf/x86: Implement cycles:p for SNB/IVB
>
> Now that there's finally a chip with working PEBS (IvyBridge), we can
>   enable the hardware and implement cycles:p for SNB/IVB.

And I think, there is no full list of such "precise" converting hack besides the linux source code in [`arch/x86/events/intel/core.c`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/x86/events/intel/core.c?v=4.8), grep for `static void intel_pebs_aliases` (usually `cycles:p` / `CPU_CLK_UNHALTED 0x003c` is implemented) and check `intel_pmu_init` for actual model and exact  `x86_pmu.pebs_aliases` variant selected:

- intel_pebs_aliases_core2, `INST_RETIRED.ANY_P (0x00c0) CNTMASK=16` instead of `cycles:p`
- intel_pebs_aliases_snb, `UOPS_RETIRED.ALL (0x01c2) CNTMASK=16` instead of `cycles:p`
- intel_pebs_aliases_precdist for highest values of `precise_ip`, `INST_RETIRED.PREC_DIST (0x01c0)` instead of `cycles:ppp` on SKL, IVB, HSW, BDW

Comment: Experiment with `perf stat -e cycles,cycles:p,instructions,task-clock ./program` show that `cycles` are not exactly equal to `cycles:p` when the hack is used. But the difference is less than 0.1%.